# Hour glass problem

Tags: combinatorics

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GRqb.png)
>
> Above is a figure that shows hour glass at different instants of time.
> It's stated that the time it takes for sand to completely flowing is
> $1.3$ hours. In the second state, after $0.5$ hours, the hour glass is
> rotated and brought to the second state in the figure. After $0.1$
> hours, the hour glass is brought to the third state and there's no
> flow of sand. Which of ratios can be ratio of the amount of sands in
> both regions? $\frac{3}{8}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{8}{9}, \frac{3}{4},
>  \frac{7}{8}$.

I approached this problem by supposing $\nu\in \mathbb{R}$ to denote the total amount of sand.

$$\nu(t) = \biggr(1-\frac{t}{1.3}\biggr)\nu + \frac{t}{1.3}\nu$$

After $0.4$ hours, the distribution of sand looks like

$$\nu(0.4) = \biggr(1-\frac{0.4}{1.3}\biggr)\nu+\frac{0.4}{1.3}\nu$$

Where $\nu_{+} = \biggr(1-\frac{0.4}{1.3}\biggr)\nu$ and $\nu_{-} = \biggr(\frac{0.4}{1.3}\biggr)\nu$ denote respectively the total amount of sand in upper and lower hour glass, and whose ratio gives us $\frac{4}{9}$.

Is my approach meaningful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total journey is $1.3$ ; We did partial journey ($0.5$), and then $0.1$ in reverse direction.  So we did $0.4$, and the remaining is $1.3-0.4=0.9$. The ratio $\frac{\text{done}}{\text{remaining}}$ is $\frac{4}{9}$